# RMarkdown com acentuações trocadas

Tags: r, codificação-de-caracteres, rmarkdown

Elaborei um relatório em Rmarkdown que, após uma atualização do Windows, ele mudou todos os acentos por outros caracteres. A questão principal seria a leitura da arquivos externos. Mas tem uma parte que preciso ler uns 'csv's', que antes o encoding "ISO-8859-1" funcionava perfeitamente, mas agora também não funciona mais. Abaixo o código de leitura:

```
arquivosRREO <- lapply(arquivosRREOLista, function(x)
  {
  arquivos <- read_delim(x,";", escape_double = FALSE, locale = locale(decimal_mark = ",", grouping_mark = ".", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", asciify = TRUE),
                         trim_ws = TRUE, skip = 5)
  arquivos <- arquivos %>% filter(UF=="RJ")

  })
```

A único evento que aconteceu da última vez que gerei os arquivos para agora foi uma atualização do windows 10. Tenho que ir testando encoding por enconding até um que funcione? E caso ache um, há alguma forma de evitar que eventos externos mexam nisso?

Comment: encoding é sempre um problema, e também é muito difícil de reproduzir. Uma das funções que mais lidam bem com encoding é o `fread` do `data.table`. Se não funcionar, eu usaria a função `stringi::stri_enc_detect` para tentar encontrar os encodings mais prováveis.

Comment: o problema de encoding é no seu arquivo `.Rmd` ou nos arquivos que você está lendo?

Comment: Nos dois! Mas o uqe me causou maior problema foi nos arquivos, pois há outros elementos que no relatório que fazem referência ao nome!